# Do while loop with a cout statement

Tags: c++, do-while

So I have a general question about the `do`/`while` loop. I'm learning C++ and I know that you can write something like that:

```
do{
....
} while(a<10 && cout<<"message");
```

The point is, that i know this is possible in c++, but do we really do that? I mean, the "`cout`" thing *inside* the while?

Comment: Just because you can doesn't mean you should, and this is a good example of that! It makes more sense to put the `cout` in the body of the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact is some people do this (i.e. run a function as part of the condition evaluation).  It makes sense in a shell script, but if you're not using a shell script, it's sometimes not clear what the return value is for some functions.  I couldn't tell you what cout<<"message" returns offhand, but I do know that if you write it inside the loop body, it would do what I want, and it would 'throw away' the return value if I don't use it.

To write cleaner code that others including your future-self can understand, I would only evaluate conditions which obviously return true/false as opposed to "0/not-0", or "0/1" which may different in different languages.

Bottom line is, let the compiler make things more efficient for you, and code for other people, not for the compiler.

Answer (score 8):

Your while loop is equivalent to

```
do {
    ...
    cout << "message";
while(a < 10 && cout);
```

because `cout << ...` returns `cout` again.
Then, the question is, what does it mean to write statements like

```
while( cout );
```

or

```
if (cout) ...
```

The `cout` object has a [conversion to boolean](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) which is used here. It's implementation is checking `!fail()`, so

```
if (cout) ...
```

is equivalent to

```
if (!cout.fail()) ...
```

and

```
do { ... }
while(cout);
```

is equivalent to

```
do { ... }
while(!cout.fail());
```

Finally, `fail` returns true if the stream [failed to produce output](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail).

Comment: Your "equivalent" code will output one more `"message"` than the original.

Comment: @molbdnilo Probably, depending on what happens to `a` inside the loop, which we don't know. Anyhow, that's not really the relevant point here as I mean to be pedagogical, but yes, they are not fully equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform the output *after* testing the condition, you would need to either do that or add another condition test inside the loop and maintain both of them, which is a bug waiting to happen.

```
do {
    if (a < 10)
        cout << "message";
} while (a < 10);
```

It's rare to see `cout <<` *by itself* in any condition though, as you can usually assume that it will succeed unless your machine is on fire.

On the other hand the *extraction* operator, `>>`, usually belongs inside a condition;

```
while (cin >> x)
```

is idiomatic C++.