# What does this snippet of code do?

Tags: c++, if-statement, input

I'm reading through the C++ Primer and they're explaining how if statements work, but I'm not sure I understand what the expression is meant to do.

```
if (std::cin >> value) {
    do etc
{
```

What is the if statement checking? I don't quite get how `std::cin >> value` can be interpreted as a boolean. Is it just checking to see if there is something for the input stream to take in?

Comment: Just take a look at `std::cin`'s `operator>>` in the docs.

Comment: Also look up  `std::ios::operator bool`

Comment: This question and answers can provide clarifications you need:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674521/how-does-while-stdcin-value-work