# How does std::cin store/interpret multiple input integers separated by a space

Tags: c++

This question was useful: [How does while (std::cin >> value) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674521/how-does-while-stdcin-value-work) but doesn't answer a few of my questions.

When running

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int sum = 0; int value = 0;

    while (std::cin >> value) {
        sum += value;
    }

    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
}
```

I then pass something like:

```
1 2 3 4 5 \n
```

to the interpreter (I guess not an interpreter, I mean the CLI). My question is how is this stored, how does it "know" to skip the spaces, how are the spaces even processed. I understand it somehow iterates over these but can't quite figure out how... Does it store an intermediate array? Is it perhaps more equivalent to something like this in pseudocode:

```
input = "1 2 3 4 5 \n"
value = input.get_next() # we look for the next non-space character
if type(value) != int:
    break
else:
    sum += value
```

also any advice on how I can figure this out by myself would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "how"? If you were to write a program, yourself, to skip spaces when reading an input stream the solution seems obvious: read one character at a time. And skip spaces. The End. And the `>>` overload does the same thing, except that when not skipping spaces the not-skipped digits get converted. Or the stream gets put into a failed state. The End. Which part of this is unclear to you, and what exactly is unclear?

Comment: My question is how does it "skip spaces", is the input stored as a string? as an array? how does it take in "1 2 3 4 5 \n" and somehow extract the ints to sum? From what I understand it somehow extracts them sequentially until it encounters something that is not an int and then breaks. But I don't understand how it is performing this iteration.

Comment: I am brand new to cpp and I'm essentially confused how me typing "1 2 3 4 5 \n" somehow results in while(std::cin >> value) iterating over the numbers within this input.

Comment: Input streams use stream buffers. [See this question for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116541/what-exactly-is-streambuf-how-do-i-use-it). Stream buffers provide an abstraction layer for reading input from an input stream one character at a time, while buffering larger chunks of time, reading one chunk at a time from the file and storing it in an internal buffer.

Comment: @AlexisDrakopoulos https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws